# Как расположить текст слева, а блок справа?

Tags: css, вёрстка

[image: набросок]

Нужна помощь. Кто знает, как сделать так, чтобы **текст** был *слева*, а *справа* был **border**.

Попробовал **обтекание (float)** - не получилось.

**Border** с *текстом* и *изображением.*

Изображение выше, набросок того, что у меня должно получиться.

```
#id1 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #222222;
    border: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    color: white;
}

#id2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быстрый набросок:

```css
body {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#id1 {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}

#id2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/800/200/300.jpg?grayscale&hmac=aVCtcPuvEXk_PkEEd6jZZ8DKvePngsyZbSNcwh_f_iA"/><p>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p></div>
<div id="id2">текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</div>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, сработало.